# Left Outer Join returning duplicate

Tags: t-sql, join, left-join

I have a scenario where i would like to override a value with another value from a cross reference table.  They can either be universal overrides or portfolio specific overrides.  My cross reference table looks like this:

```
SEDOL    Portfolio    Override
1        1            Technology
1        2            Financial
1        NULL         Industrial
2        NULL         Technology
3        NULL         Financial
```

If portfolio is NULL then it is a universal override, if it has a portfolio number then it is a portfolio specific override.

So then my select would look like this:

```
SELECT
          Portfolio
      ,   SEDOL
      ,   CASE
              WHEN hack.SEDOL = ia.SEDOL AND hack.Portfolio = ia.Portfolio THEN hack.Override  -- Portfolio Specific Hack
              WHEN hack.SEDOL = ia.SEDOL AND hack.Portfolio IS NULL THEN hack.Override              -- Hack for all portfolio's
              ELSE ia.Sector
          END

FROM positions as ia

     LEFT OUTER JOIN DP_CrossReference AS hack  -- Override/Hacks
          ON hack.SEDOL = ia.SEDOL
          AND (hack.Portfolio = ia.Portfolio OR hack.Portfolio IS NULL)
```

I seem to be getting duplicates however for portfolio 1 where the portfolio specific override is being returned and the universal override is being returned for SEDOL 1.  I thought the case statemt would be sufficient to sort this.  Its got to be my join to DP_CrossReference.  How can i join to this table so that i don't get a duplicate but so it covers specific portfolio overrides, universal overrides and postitions without an override?

Comment: If you have SEDOL= 1 AND Portfolio = 1, which override should take? You have portfolio and universal overrides on same value. That's where duplicate from.

Comment: This was only example data, this wasn't the issue with my actual data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, please try this.

```
SELECT
          ia.Portfolio
      ,   ia.SEDOL
      ,   COALESCE(ov1.Override,ov2.Override, ia.Sector)
FROM positions as ia
LEFT OUTER JOIN DP_CrossReference AS ov1 --  portfolio specific overrides
          ON ov1.SEDOL = ia.SEDOL
          AND ov1.Portfolio = ia.Portfolio
LEFT OUTER JOIN DP_CrossReference AS ov2 -- universal overrides 
          ON ov2.SEDOL = ia.SEDOL
          AND ov2.Portfolio IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for that, splitting the join from 1 into 2 seems to have done the trick.